# My Woocommerce website isn't redirecting to cart or checkout page anymore

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

our website is running at [koh samui tours](https://www.kohsamuitour.net). All was working fine until this morning, when all of a sudden we don't get any bookings through Woocommerce bookings anymore. It seems that the button 'Book now' on a product page is not sending the customer to the checkout page, but just reloads the current page.

My console isn't showing anything weird, and error logs show nothing strange. I am really lost, can anyone help me to see what's going on?

Comment: Did you tried like this <input type="submit" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button add_to_cart_button  product_type_simple button alt" value="book now" />

Comment: your website is working fine, it is not redirecting to checkout immediately but it adds the booking to the cart, the real issue is when I press book now it shows that I have to fill the above options despite I chose the date and the  count of adults already set to 1

Comment: http://prnt.sc/dktzij

Comment: that actually works, but its calculating the price on the background. Only when the calculated price shows up a product can be booked. I find that annoying too because it needs to show some kind of loader that spins while the price is being calculated. Wondering if that is possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just be sure that this option is ticked:

WP admin panel > WooCommerce >products > display

find the option that says redirect to the cart page after successful addition and tick it
[image: Steps for redirecting user to cart in WooCommerce]

Comment: that must have been removed when I updated woocommerce. very strange, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in functions.php and try.

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
   global $woocommerce;
   $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
   return $checkout_url;
}
```